# Método eficiente para abaixar ordem de matrizes em PHP

Tags: php, desempenho, matriz

Estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora de determinante em PHP

Na classe Matrix eu criei algumas funções, dentre elas a função calc(ordem, matriz).
Essa função chama uma outra para abaixar a ordem da matriz até $ordem=3, e logo após executa a função sarrus($matriz).

> **Nota:** Essa variável matriz será alterada sempre que for abaixada a ordem, ou seja, a matriz original ficará salva em uma outra variável!

Pois bem, desejo saber qual o melhor método para abaixar a ordem da matriz até 3, se possível um exemplo de código, tentei usar laplace mas eu me confundi muito nos loops q resolvi desistir por um tempo.

```
public function calc($ordem, $matriz)
{
    //Se a ordem for igual a 1: o elemento é o determinante
    if ($ordem == 1) {
        $this->det = $matriz[0][0];
    }
    //Se a ordem for igual a 2: chama a função @segOrdem
    else if ($ordem == 2) {
        segOrdem($matriz);
    }
    //Se a ordem for 3: chama a função @sarrus
    else if ($ordem == 3) {
        sarrus($matriz);
    }
    //Se a ordem for maior que 3: chama a função @abaixarOrdem para abaixar a ordem da matriz até 3 e logo após usar @sarrus para se ter o determinante
    else if ($ordem > 3) {
        $matriz = abaixarOrdem($matriz, $ordem);
        sarrus($matriz);
    }
    return $this->det;
}
```

**O layout da matriz:**

```
$matriz = array( 
            array(1,2,3), 
            array(4,5,6), 
            array(7,8,9) 
          );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criei uma solução usando a regra de [Chiò](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felice_Chi%C3%B2). Para o exemplo, eu usei o seguinte array:

```
    $matriz = [
        [1,2,5,3,2],
        [1,3,7,3,4], 
        [0,5,2,2,1], 
        [1,3,0,1,2], 
        [0,6,7,4,7] 
    ];
```

Para conseguir seguir essa regra, usei o [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php) para pegar toda a primeira coluna e usei o índice `0` do array para pegar a primeira linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desta forma, pude fazer a multiplicação e a subtração de cada elemento usando recursividade. Repare que o loop começa do `1`. Pois assim é ignorado tanto a primeira coluna quanto a primeira linha da matriz sem a necessidade de usar o `unset`(já que você pediu performance)

```
    $novaMatriz = abaixarOrdem($matriz);
    print_r($novaMatriz);

function abaixarOrdem($matriz) {

    $ordem = count($matriz[0]);
    $coluna = array_column($matriz, 0);
    $linha  = $matriz[0];
    $novaMatriz = [];

    for($x = 1; $x < $ordem; $x++){

        for($y = 1; $y < $ordem; $y++){
            // aqui é calculado o valor do elemento 
            // multiplicando o valor das colunas e subtraindo o número da matriz
            $valor = $matriz[$x][$y] - ($coluna[$x] * $linha[$y]);
            $novaMatriz[$x - 1][$y - 1] = $valor;
        }

    }
    if(count($novaMatriz[0]) > 3)
        $novaMatriz = abaixarOrdem($novaMatriz); // refaz até ser ordem 3
    return $novaMatriz;
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
    [-8, 2,-9]
    [-7,-2,-2]
    [-5, 4,-5]
```

**Observação**

> Eu não criei a permutação para o caso do índice [0][0] da matriz não
>   seja 1.  Assim como não apliquei o [Teorema de Jacobi](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_Jacobi) caso não
>   haja o valor 1 na matriz. Esta solução é apenas um exemplo para
>   **abaixamento da ordem da matriz**

Comment: Nossa cara valeu mesmo, eu dei uma melhorada no código e está perfeito! Muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: Eu estava muito confuso na hora de criar os loops

Comment: @SampaioLeal tranquilo! Se quiser sugerir alguma edição, pode inserir!

Comment: @SampaioLeal sim... Eu também fiquei um pouco confuso! Esse problema me deu um pouco de trabalho para criar uma solução...  =) Abraço!

Comment: @SampaioLeal depois dá uma olhada na classe que eu criei! https://gist.github.com/andrei-coelho/a355fefa98473371d30827aae01db2f2